# Unable to access my profile/accounts in Thunderbird Portable

Tags: thunderbird, import

I have a [Thunderbird Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable) install in an external HDD, connected via USB. It's been working fine for years, but lately I purchased an extension cable for the HDD usb cable and it lead to I/O issues. Thunderbird crashed and **now whenever I start TB I can't find my profile data** (even some settings seem to have been reset, but it finds my addons).

I can see the emails are still stored in the portable installation folder, under `Data` > `profile`. I tried importing this profile folder as described here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-import , but whenever I use either `Import from another TB installation` or `Import from a file` > `Import Back-up Profile` > `Choose profile folder`, it finds the profile and starts the import process. *However, after TB restarts to finish the process, nothing is changed!* Nothing was imported and I still have no account.

##### Q: How can I restore my previous TB accounts?

setup: Win 10 x64, latest, TB 102.06

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was debugging TB as I was asking this and found the answer!

I think the I/O drive error somehow deleted the link in my profile folder `prefs.js` file to the profile data and accounts. When I entered the profile folder, I noticed my original `prefs.js` file was renamed to `prefs-1.js`. I think this prefs file is responsible for locating accounts and such, and TB created a new one for a new account from scratch.

**So all I had to do to make Thunderbird Portable work again was rename my old prefs file to `prefs.js` again (instead of `prefs-2.js`).** I restarted TB and now it works! I lost so many hours on this, I hope this can be useful for someone facing the same problem